# How do I work with large, memory hungry numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, matplotlib

I have a program which creates an array:

```
List1 = zeros((x, y), dtype=complex_)
```

Currently I am using `x = 500` and `y = 1000000`.
I will initialize the first column of the list by some formula. Then the subsequent columns will calculate their own values based on the preceding column.
After the list is completely filled, I will then display this multidimensional array using `imshow()`.

The size of each value (item) in the list is `24` bytes.
A sample value from the code is: `4.63829355451e-32`

When I run the code with `y = 10000000`, it takes up too much RAM and the system stops the run. How do I solve this problem? Is there a way to save my RAM while still being able to process the list using `imshow()` easily? Also, how large a list can `imshow()` display?

Comment: numpy requires contiguous memory (to do pretty much any operation) .. 32bit applications are limited to 2gb of ram per process as a hard limit. ... you might need to use a database to store the data on disk rather than in memory (this will slow down everything ...)

Comment: Numpy complex numbers take 16 bytes each, so it sounds like that will need 80 GB of RAM, which is probably more than you have. If you have multiple machines available, you may be able to use some kind of distributed array library (see e.g. [distarray](http://docs.enthought.com/distarray/)). If not, you could look at storing the data on disk in a format like HDF5 (see [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/)), though as Joran says, this will be slower. You could also rethink what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also note that you computer screen is only a few 1000 pixels wide, so visualizing an image `500x10000000`  really does not make sense (it will take 1hour 40min to scroll through it at 1 page/second in native resolution, even if it was possible). If you really need to do it, follow @ThomasK suggestions above (or use `numpy.memmap` , [`dask.array`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) etc for storage) then subsample your data and plot only a small fraction of it with `imshow`.

Answer (score 4):

**There's no way to solve this problem** (in any general way).

Computers ([as commonly understood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture)) have a limited amount of RAM, and they require elements to be in RAM in order to operate on them.

An `complex128` array size of `10000000x500` would require around 74GiB to store. **You'll need to somehow reduce the amount of data you're processing** if you hope to use a regular computer to do it (as opposed to a [supercomputer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercomputer)).

A common technique is partitioning your data and processing each partition individually (possibly on multiple computers). Depending on the problem you're trying to solve, there may be special data structures that you can use to reduce the amount of memory needed to represent the data - a good example is a [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix).

**It's very unusual to need this much memory** - make sure to carefully consider if it's *actually needed* before you dwell into the extremely complex workarounds.